# Double click action not working whereas single click works on an element in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, double-click

I am trying to double click on an element but unable to perform the action. Single click works fine on the same element. Am i missing something?. Can someone please help me out with this.

HTML of the element:

```
<tbody><tr class="mclS" tabindex="0"> <td><div class="mclC" style="height:14px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;Quarter&nbsp;to&nbsp;Date</div></td> </tr> </tbody>
```

I have tried various ways of double clicking the element:

```
WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mlstBody>tbody>tr:nth-child(8)"));

=> actions.doubleClick(date).build().perform();

=> actions.doubleClick(date);

=> ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" + "evt.initMouseEvent('dblclick',true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0,null);" + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);",date);

=> actions.moveToElement(date).doubleClick().build();
actions.perform();
```

Comment: @Brian I tried this approach aswell but still don't work.

Comment: What are you attempting to double click on?

Comment: i am trying to double click on a element in the list, when i perform double click action it will just scroll through the list where the element is present but does not double click on that element. Single click works perfectly fine if i use date.click().. If i use actions.click(date).perform() it does not click on that element.

Comment: @Ayisha Update the question with the relevant HTML and the information on which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ?

Comment: @DebanjanB i am using Java and i have updated the HTML

Comment: @Ayisha I still don't see the relevant HTML

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess you are using Firefox?  I think there is an issue written up with doubleclick and the geckodriver.  I don't think it's fixed yet.  I see you tried one way in JavaScript.  Can you try this way though?  It worked for me in Firefox.

```
document.querySelector(".mlstBody>tbody>tr:nth-child(8)").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("dblclick"));
```

Comment: I am using chrome to automate and i tried with your suggestion but still does not double click.

Comment: You say when you doubleclick the element, the value populates a textbox.  Why are we not getting the full HTML then?  The html you have given us has no textbox shown.  If we are to properly help you, then you need to give us everything we can to do so.  Right now we are just shooting in the dark and giving guesses.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you were pretty close. To invoke `doubleClick()` through `Actions` class you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement date = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("tr.mclS>td>div.mclC")));
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(date).doubleClick().build().perform();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement date = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//tr[@class='mclS']/td/div[@class='mclC' and contains(.,'Date')]")));
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(date).doubleClick().build().perform();
  ```

---

### Update

As you are still unable to invoke `doubleClick()` on the desired element as an alternative to make **Mouse Double Click** you can write a script and pass it to the `executeScript()` method as follows:

- Script :

  ```
  String jsDoubleClick = 
    "var target = arguments[0];                                 " +
    "var offsetX = arguments[1];                                " +
    "var offsetY = arguments[2];                                " + 
    "var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();                 " +
    "var cx = rect.left + (offsetX || (rect.width / 2));        " +        
    "var cy = rect.top + (offsetY || (rect.height / 2));        " +
    "                                                           " +
    "emit('mousedown', {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, buttons: 1}); " +
    "emit('mouseup',   {clientX: cx, clientY: cy});             " +
    "emit('mousedown', {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, buttons: 1}); " +
    "emit('mouseup',   {clientX: cx, clientY: cy});             " +
    "emit('click',     {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, detail: 2});  " +
    "                                                           " +
    "function emit(name, init) {                                " +
      "target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(name, init));        " +
    "}                                                          " ;
  ```
- Invoking the script through `executeScript()` from your `@Test` :

  ```
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(myElem, posX, posY).perform();
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(jsDoubleClick, myElem, posX, posY);
  ```

Comment: Tried both the ways you suggested but still doesn't work. Please let me know if there is approach.

Comment: @Ayisha Your comment doesn't helps me either. Sorry, the answer didn't help you to solve your problem but how am I going to improve my post with that feedback?

Comment: sry there was a typo error in my previous comment. I wanted to know if there is anyother way of achieving the double click on the element.

Comment: @Ayisha Can you update the question with some more information, why do you need to `doubleClick()` instead of a `click()`

Comment: when I double click the element the value gets populated in the text box.

Comment: So where are you exactly stuck? Does `findElement()` return exception or `moveToElement()` return exception or `doubleClick()` is not getting executed?

Comment: I am able to locate the element but unable to perform double click. If i try single click with element.click() it clicks on the element but if I try clicking with actions.click(element) it does not click.          findElement() and moveToElement() doesn't return any exception.

Comment: @Ayisha Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Tried with the updated code but still does not double click.

Comment: @Ayisha Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Tried with the updated answer but still does not double click.

Answer (score 0):

For [reference](https://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/double-click-in-selenium-webdriver-java.html).

You need to perform the action on the element like this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mlstBody>tbody>tr:nth-child(8)"));
action.doubleClick(date).perform();
```

**NOTE:**  This example uses Java.

**Additional NOTE:**  For Selenium 3.5 and up, you will need to do the following:

```
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".msltBody>tbody>tr:nth-child(8)")).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

Comment: Tried even that but nothing seems to work. Is there any other way to double click?